# Does anyone know why this is happening with 1/7?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

(I've never posted on here before, so apologies for any formatting problems)

I had always noticed this property of the decimal form of $1/7$ ( $0.14285714...$ ) where the decimals went $14$ , then $28$ , then $57$ , which is almost exactly the formula $f(x)=7*2^x$ , starting with $f(1)$ - except for $57$ , which is $1$ more than $56$. However, if you add the next number in the series, $f(4)=112$ , to the tail end of $56$, then you get $57$ and are left with the second $1$ and the $2$ to add to the end of the decimal, which is **exactly** where the $71$ lands in the $.14285714...$ string of digits. If you keep doing this with the next number in the formula, $f(5)=224$ , and add to the end of $112$ , you get $2+2$ , which accounts the $4$ and the $2$ , and so on.

I continued this pattern and found that this process of adding digits together works all the way up to the $45th$ digit , which is where I stopped. Is this simply a coincidence or is there a reason for this to occur? And if there really is something behind this (which I'm sure there is, does anyone know why this happens? I would appreciate any attempt at solving this.

[Work for said question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHnJX.jpg) (apologies if it's messy, I did this work in a cramped notebook lol) I know this seems very confusing, but if anyone needs me to clarify, I will do my best.

Comment: $100 \div 7$ has remainder $2$

Comment: Wait I just realized that what I was doing was essentially long division, whoopsies lol

Comment: For your concatenation of $f(x)$ results, divide your $f(x) = 7\cdot 2^x$ by $100^x$:
$$\frac{f(x)}{100^x} = 7\cdot 0.02^x$$
Then your hypothesis becomes that $1/7$ is equal to the geometric series $$7\cdot 0.02^1 + 7\cdot 0.02^2 +\cdots \overset ?= \frac17$$

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365506/doubling-sequences-of-the-cyclic-decimal-parts-of-the-fraction-numbers), [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2457084/recurring-decimal-expansion-of-frac17), and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4667517/is-there-a-reason-why-frac17-as-a-decimal-so-perfectly-seems-to-follow-mu/4678061#4678061)

Comment: it is true that...
$$\frac 17 = 7\sum_{n=1}^\infty(0.02)^n$$
And that the sum formula for geometric series gives...
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty(0.02)^n  =  \frac{50}{49}$$

Answer (score 3):

It is Geometric Progression with the Co-Incidence that $50 = 7 \times 7+1$

When we are appending 2 Digits , we are using $100^n$ Denominator , while the Numerator is what you gave $7 \times 2^n$

Adding up the terms for all $n$ will give this :
$X = 7 \times \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n = 7 \times x/(1-x)$ , where $x = 2/100=1/50$

We can then see that $x/(1-x)=1/49$
Hence $X=7 \times 1/49 = 1/7$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242.)